# rewriting array into a new one in cleaner manner

Tags: php

Looking for an elegant way to rewrite this mess in php, obviously there are many lines of if else, something shorter and sweeter would be awesome.

```
foreach ( $respArr[ 'opt' ] as $k => $v ) {

            if ( $v == 'AirbagsFront' ) { $car[ 'opt_o' ][ 'Airbags' ] = 1; } else
            if ( $v == 'AlarmSystem' ) { $car[ 'opt_o' ][ 'Alarm' ] = 1; }          

        }
```

Input:

```
["AlarmSystem","AirbagsFront"]
```

Expected output:

```
"opt_o":{"Airbags":1,"Alarm":1}
```

hope you don't mind me showing json instead of arrays.

Comment: Maybe something like this will help you: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way using an associative array to define the map, which makes it easy to add/remove mappings:

```
$map = array(
    'AirbagsFront' => 'Airbags',
    'AlarmSystem' => 'Alarm',
);

foreach ($respArr['opt'] as $v) {
    if(isset($map[$v])) {
        $car['opt_o'][$map[$v]] = 1;
    }
}
```